# Django, CBV, form.py, несколько моделей и один шаблон

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте уважаемые знатоки!
Есть вопрос следующего характера:

есть модель(ли)

```py
models.py

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Phone(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    person_id = ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Вывести через форму модель - **Person** - я понимаю как:

```py
forms.py

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__' #так пишу для упрощения
```

```py
views.py

class PersonListView(ListView):
    model = Person
```

```html
person_list.html

{% block content %}
    {% for person in person_list %}
    <p><a href={% url 'person_detail' person.id %}>{{person.name}}</a></p>
    <p></p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Может быть я не правильно понимаю саму концепцию **Forms** ?
Чтобы просто вывести на страницу записи из БД форму не нужно использовать, достаточно взять из **Class-based Views** подкласс **ListView** и через него вывести данные на страницу?
Если так, то как правильно вывести детальную информацию по персоне с номерами телефонов, как совместить модели и зависимость? Как я понимаю через **DetailView**
Можно пример как правильно это реализовать с учётом того, что у персон может быть разное число номеров.

И для чего нужны **Forms**? только для вводов  и редактирования записей в БД?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе все верно формы нужны для ввода данных пользователем и их последующей проверки.
Не обязательно после этого идет сохранение в базу данных, это может быть форма с фильтрами для поиска
после которой нужно не сохранить данные, а просто отфильтровать данные на странице.

Так же формы делятся на `Form` и `ModelForm`
В `Form` ты самостоятельно определяешь список полей, которые необходимо ввести, а так же самостоятельно определяешь правила по которым решаешь, что данные пользователя верны, например у тебя может быть три поля A, B, C и для тебя важно, что бы были введены  любые два.

`ModelForm` - развитие концепции форм для ввода данных модели. В них джанго автоматически определяет список и типы полей, на основании описания твоей модели. Так же автоматически прописывает некоторые правила для введенных данных. Например если у тебя поле в модели стоит `unique=True`, то `ModelForm` автоматически проверит, что введенные пользователем данные не дублируют другую запись в БД и в противном случае сформирует сообщение об ошибке. Надо сказать, что в `ModelForm` помимо полей из модели, ты можешь дополнительно добавлять другие поля и форма будет строится на основании данных модели и добавленных тобой полей. Это может быть например в форме регистрации доп. поле, которое отвечает нужно ли отправить пользователю уведомление на e-mail после ввода данных.
Так же `ModelForm` автоматически умеет сохранять данные введенные пользователем в модель(добавлять или обновлять)

Следующим развитием работы с введенными пользовательскими данными являются `Formset` - это возможность за раз показывать несколько форм пользователю и соответственно затем проверять введенные данные и если нужно сохранять в БД. По аналогии с формами есть `Formset` и `ModelFormset` соответственно первый содержит набор из `Form` второй из `ModelForm`
Ну и разумеется всю подробную информацию можно найти в документации джанго:
[Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django), [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform), [Formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/#formsets), [ModelFormset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets)

По поводу DetailView в [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) все подробно описано.
Тебе нужно создать DetailView, указать модель на основании которой оно будет строится. Затем тебе нужно в urls.py добавить конфигурацию урл, которое ведет на эту форму и в нем указать либо `id`, либо `slug` поле, по которому твою запись можно однозначно найти

По поводу того, как получить информацию о списке телефонов для конкретного пользователя.
Во первых я бы изначально во все ссылки на другие модели добавлял поле `related_name`
`person_id = ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='phones')`
и тогда что бы получить список телефонов по данному `person`, ты можешь использовать `person.phones.all()` или если, нужно использовать фильтры `person.phones.filter(phone__startwith="+7")`.
Можно не добавлять `related_name` и django автоматически будет создавать `modelname_set` (`phone_set` в твоем случае), но если у тебя две ссылки на одну и ту же модель, то тут django будет бросать исключение, так как две обратные ссылки будут иметь одинаковое имя. Поэтому лучше сразу приучить себя использовать
`related_name`

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо за столь подробный ответ!!!! Спасибо!!!
А в DetailView мне нужно указывать модель **Phone** ? А имя, чьи телефоны я подробно смотрю передать через URL как person_id и потом в DetailView передать в виде дополнительного context ?

Comment: Если у тебя идет просмотр пользователя, я бы передал model Person, а через доп. контекст список телефонов. Как раз и передаешь ты person_id(только назвать его надо как ключ в таблице (`id` по умолчанию)), DetailView автоматически найдет тебе объект Person. Если будешь передавать `Phone  и `person_id`, когда у пользователя будет несколько телефонов DetailView будет ругаться, что нельзя однозначно определить объект по ключу person_id

Comment: Огромное спасибо!
Я вот так сделал:
"
view.py

class PersonDetail(DetailView):
    model = Person
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        rez = PhoneNumber.objects.filter(person_id_id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["phones"] = rez
        return context
"
"
urls.py

path('person/id=<int:pk>/', views.PersonDetail.as_view(), name='person_detail'),
"

Answer (score 0):

Если вдруг кому пригодится хочу привести моё решение задачи. Огромное спасибо @AndreyMaslov за советы

как можно получить список телефонов Персоны с помощью ***DetailView***

здесь мы используем модель ***Person*** и переопределяем метод ***get_context_data***, добавляя в него все телефоны, которые относятся к конкретной персоне (я допустил ошибку при названии поля: person_id, надо быть просто написать person, потому как _id к названию Django само добавит. Из-за этого у меня получилось person_id_id)

```py
urls.py
....
path('person/id=<int:pk>/', views.PersonDetail.as_view(), name='person_detail'),
....
```

```py
views.py

class PersonDetail(DetailView):
    model = Person
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        phones = PhoneNumber.objects.filter(person_id_id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["phones"] = phones
        return context
```

```html
person_detail.py

{% block content %}
    <p>Name: {{person.name}}
    <p>-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--==-=-=-==-=--=-==-=-=--==</p>
    <p><u>Phones</u></p>
    {% for phone in phones %}
    <p>  .................    {{phone}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

И вариант с добавлением в модель поля ***related_name=''*** (добавляем его в модель ***Phone***)

```
models.py
 .....

class Phone(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    person_id = ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='phones')
```

и тогда можно сделать так:

```py
views.py

class PersonDetail(DetailView):
    model = Person
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        temp = Person.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        phones = temp.phones.all() # этот phones из модели Phone
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["phones"] = phones
        return context
```

шаблон остаётся тот же, что чуть ранее