# Django, в одну форму поля нескольких моделей

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Изучаю Django и в продолжении моего [предыдущего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1191455/django-cbv-form-py-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD) ещё один вопрос:

есть две модели:

```py
models.py

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Phone(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    person = ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

создать просто Персону не трудно

```py
forms.py

class PersonAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'
```

```py
views.py

class AddPerson(CreateView):
    model = Person
    form_class = PersonAddForm
    template_name = "person_add.html"
    
    def success_url(self):
        return redirect("/person/")
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return redirect("/person/")
```

```html
person_add.html

{% block content %}
    <p>Add New Person
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Create New</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

А как можно сделать так, чтобы с добавлением новой Персоны можно было бы сразу добавлять телефоны в этой же форме? Наверное правильно сказать один телефон (одно поле в модели), а хотелось бы чтобы сразу можно сколько нужно телефонов добавлять (типа нажимая кнопку "добавить номер" и появляется ещё одно поле на форме для ввода)

Спасибо!

Comment: Вам нужен [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/)

Comment: а можно какой-нибудь пример ?
а то что есть в Сети не очень понятно

Answer (score 0):

Вот такое решение я нашёл. Как я понимаю оно не самое оптимальное и правильное. Правильно использовать **InlineFormSet_factory**, но как это правильно делать я так и не понял
Привожу того, как у меня получилось

```
models.py

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Phone(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    person = ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
forms.py

class PersonForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('name',)

class PhoneForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Phone
        fields = ('phone',)
```

```
views.py

class AddPerson(CreateView):
    template_name = 'app_1/addperson.html'
    person_form = PersonForm()
    phone_form = PhoneForm()

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {'person': self.person_form, 'phone': self.phone_form}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        person_form = PersonForm(request.POST)
        phone_form = PhoneForm(request.POST)
        if (person_form.is_valid() and phone_form.is_valid()):
            per_f = person_form.save()
            ph_f = phone_form.save(commit=False)
            ph_f.person_id = per_f.id
            ph_f.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/app_1/add-person/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/app_1/add-person/')
```

А вот как можно сделать создание персоны и сразу добавление номера телефона используя **InlineFormSet_factory** ?